# Flutter widget rebuilding when clicking on icon

Tags: flutter, widget

A gif i better than words, but to describe the problem, i have a searchbar to search in a list. It returns results, but when i click on a result for some information (info icon), it restarts a search, so the page is being rebuild, when i press on OK, it reports "Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe".
I understand that the problem comes from the refresh, but i don't know why a refresh is called, i'm just pressing a button

Edit : It seems to be something related to the build method and the keyboard.. But i don't know what is bad in my code..

```
class HistoriquePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String pageName;
  final String namespace;

  const HistoriquePage({Key? key, required this.pageName, required this.namespace}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HistoriquePageState createState() => _HistoriquePageState();
}

class _HistoriquePageState extends State<HistoriquePage> {
  final _debounce = Debounce();
  DateTimeRange? dateRange;
  String searchedValue = "";
  Post? user;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _debounce.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _sendSearch(String value) {
    _debounce.run(() {
      setState(() {
        searchedValue = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.pageName),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: DateRangeField(
                      enabled: true,
                      // initialValue: DateTimeRange(
                      //     // start: DateTime.parse("2020-01-01"),
                      //     end: DateTime.now()),
                      firstDate: new DateTime(2020),
                      helpText: 'Sélectionnez un interval de dates',
                      fieldStartLabelText: 'Date de début',
                      fieldEndLabelText: 'Date de fin',
                      fieldStartHintText: 'Début',
                      fieldEndHintText: 'Fin',
                      dateFormat: DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'),
                      saveText: 'OK',
                      // initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.input,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        // labelText: 'Interval de temps pour la recherche',
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.date_range, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        hintText: 'Sélectionnez un intervalle de dates',

                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Specific.getWhite),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          dateRange = value!;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Sélectionnez le composant',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Specific.getWhite)),
                    onChanged: _sendSearch),
              ),
              Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150, child: ComponentsHistoriqueDeployment(searchedValue, dateRange: dateRange))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));
}
```

[image]

EDIT :

```
class ComponentsHistoriqueDeployment extends StatelessWidget {
  final String searchedValue;
  final DateTimeRange? dateRange;

  ComponentsHistoriqueDeployment(this.searchedValue, {this.dateRange});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
        future: HistoriqueService.fetchHistorique(searchedValue, dateRange: dateRange),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            final result = snapshot.data!;
            if (result.length > 0) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
                child: ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
                    itemCount: result.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                            child: Badge(
                              toAnimate: true,
                              animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                              shape: BadgeShape.square,
                              badgeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              badgeContent: Text(result[index].name, style: TextStyle(color: Specific.getWhite, fontSize: 16)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          _displayMoreInformationOnComponent(result, index, context)
                        ]),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            } else {
              return _noResultFound();
            }
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }
}

Widget _noResultFound() {
  return Container(
    child: new Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: const <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.warning_outlined,
            color: Colors.orange,
            size: 50.0,
            semanticLabel: "Attention : Aucun résultat n'a été trouvé...",
          ),
          Text(
            "Aucun résultat n'a été trouvé...",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _displayMoreInformationOnComponent(result, index, context) {
  return Container(
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text('Tag: ' + result[index].username),
      subtitle: Text('Date: ' + result[index].address.street),
      leading: Icon(Icons.label),
      trailing: Wrap(
        spacing: 20,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            onPressed: () => Dialogs.bottomMaterialDialog(
                msgStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                msg: 'Tag: ' +
                    result[index].name +
                    '\nStatus: ' +
                    result[index].name +
                    '\nDernier déploiement: ' +
                    result[index].name +
                    '\nType de route: ' +
                    result[index].name +
                    '\nDernier commit par: ' +
                    result[index].name +
                    '\n',
                title: result[index].name,
                color: Specific.getOrange,
                context: context,
                actions: [
                  IconsButton(
                    text: "OK",
                    iconData: Icons.check_circle,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Specific.getWhite),
                    iconColor: Specific.getWhite,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Can I see the code of `ComponentsHistoriqueDeployment` class?

Comment: Yes ok i edit it in 1 minute

Comment: @CelesKang For your information, the problems occurs too if i comment the container that lauch ComponentsHistoriqueDeployment.
It occurs too if i comment onChanged values.
For information, each time i tap/click on the input textfield, it rebuild my widget..
Each time i focus and i go out..

Comment: The same problem seems to be here too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512380/flutter-state-rebuild-when-keyboard-appears

Comment: Then did you try removing `MedaiQurey.of(context)...`  here in this code? 
```Container(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150, child: ComponentsHistoriqueDeployment(searchedValue, dateRange: dateRange))
```?

Comment: Yes already tried, but the problem of rebuild is again present (when i click to unfocus the textfield it start things to rebuild in the background). the problem is the textfield for sure

Comment: Then I think this might be the problem. So whenever the state (here, `searchedValue`) changes, it will rebuild the whole things in `build` method of `_HistoriquePageState` and so will ` ComponentsHistoriqueDeployment` inside of it and so will ` _displayMoreInformationOnComponent` inside. Then `FutureBuilder` inside will be rebuilt, which calls `Future` again. So maybe try adding conditional in `onChanged` of the `TextField` where you type the search keyword to call `_sendSearch` only when the `value` in `TextField` is different from the present value of `searchedValue`.

Comment: I don't think that's good to do that, i will wait answers from users with experience :) I'm a new one ;)

Comment: Of course it's not good to do I just suggested the simplest possible way. You already answered yourself. Don't let the `FutureBuilder` to rebuild again whenever the state changes. That's quite insulting what you say though.

Comment: ? I said that i'm a new :) So i don't have any experience on flutter :) It's why i'm waiting for some users with a lot of experience :)